# Modulus division operator, with offset?

Tags: php

I have a loop:

```
foreach ($arr as $_k => $_v) {
    if($_k % 6 == 0){

        //do something
    }
}
```

I need "something" to happen every sixth loop, but I need an offset of 2. So it would happen in loop 2, 8, 14 etc.

How can this be achieved?

Furthermore, I also need the "something" to happen on offsets of 4 too. So 4, 10, 16 etc.

Is this possible in the same operator or would I need an or statement?

Comment: So use `if ($_k % 6 == 2)` or `if ($_k % 6 == 4)`?

Comment: `@if` is not going to do anything useful for you.

Comment: @lonesomeday I disagree. It looks much more sophisticated!

Answer (score 3):

Just change the comparison.

```
if ($_k % 6 == 2) {
   ...
}

if ($_k % 6 == 4) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough

```
$_k % 6 == 2
```

Or more generally

```
$_k % 6 == offset
```

For your case if you need to do something different at offset 2 and 4, you will need to do two if statements.

```
if ($_k % 6 == 2)
{
 ...
} else if ($_k % 6 == 4)
{
 ...
}
```